# How can I find out the frame rate of a flash (.FLV) video from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flash, flv, frame-rate

I have some limited experience using the Flash JavaScript API to observe and manipulate SWF files. I would now like to observe and manipulate FLV videos from JavaScript. The API that I am familar with (`Play()`, `TotalFrames()`, `TCurrentFrame()`, `GotoFrame()`, etc.) operates in frames, whereas I want to operate in seconds.

So either I need an Flash JavaScript API that is based on time, or I need a way to find out the frame rate of an FLV from JavaScript, so I can translate frames into seconds and vice versa.

Note that I do not have control over the generation of the FLV files.

Comment: Do it from within in flash anything in javascript is nothing but a dirty hack

Comment: I can't avoid JavaScript. I have a JavaScript application that uses the HTML5 JavaScript API to observe and control a running video. I want to enhance this code to also support FLV video played by the flash player. I don't want to re-implement my entire app in flash. It should be a simple matter to add support for the flash player. I only need to do a few simple things, like stop/start the video, find the current position, and seek to a new position. I have already done these things successfully from JavaScript in past projects. The only missing piece is translating between frames and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question is about 4 years old, but I needed to know how to find the frame rate of an FLV file tonight, because I was needing to strip the files from the FLV container and repackage the files in to an MP4 container without doing any actual converting. I followed a tutorial on youtube which showed me how to do that using 2 apps "FLV Extract v1.6.4" and "YAMB-2.1.0.0_beta2". The only problem was that YAMB needed to know what frame rate to repackage everything as and I did not know if I should use 25, 30, etc... I noticed the guy in the youtube tutorial had another app in his folder called "MediaInfo" which he did not talk about, but I googled it and gave it a try> and it showed me that the frame of my FLV file was 30fps.

Here is the link to where I downloaded MediaInfo. http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/mediainfo_lite.html

Here is the link to the youtube video where the guy explained how to strip the files from the FLV and repackage as MP4. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87UHvc6XgYc